# Cannot get UDP socket to Bind

Tags: udp, ios7

I have been trying for two weeks to send a character via UDP.  So far I have not been able to find an example that actually works using XCode and IOS 7.  I am currently stuck as every time I run my code the Bind function returns a -1.   I have no clue as to what is wrong or what the solution is.  PS. I know my to Address is missing but for now I am just trying to get by the Bind issue.  (Examples to use a specific address have failed to compile.)

This is very frustration as I have successfully create UPD programs on Windows, Windows Mobile 6.0, and AS400 without as much effort as I have had to spend on this and so far nothing to show.

Here is my current code

```
    char Buff[256];

    strcpy(Buff,"Test MESSAGE");
    int handle = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (handle > 0) {
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address.sin_port = htons(311);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.121.8.54", &(address.sin_addr));
        if (bind(handle,(struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))< 0){
            printf("************************ Failed to bind\n");
        } else {
            send(handle, Buff, sizeof(Buff), 0);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Faile to create socket\n");
    }//end if
```

Here are my imports

```
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <fcntl.h>
#import <netdb.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: When you get an error, don't just print a message of your own devising. Print the *error.* In this case, use 'perror()', or make up an error string with 'strerror'. When you've done that, either the problem will become clear to you and you can solve it yourself, or else post the error here. Until then, this is not a real question.

Comment: Added the perror() and the error I am getting is Permission Denied.  I found an article that told me I needed to go into Xcode and under Product Scheme and change the option for Debug Process as to root; however, this option is grayed out.   Tried searching for a way to enable but did not find anything useful; found a lot that is outdated.

Comment: Finally found out that the port I was using was not allowed.  Changed to a different port number and it now works.